# Emit of websocket is repeaded on vuejs and vuex

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, websocket, vuejs2

There is a function in vuex file like below.
When I run start function using 'Button' of Vue component, 
socket.emit sends the data to socker of nodejs. 
And it receives some result through socket.on by websocket of nodejs.

```
// In vuex.js

const actions = {
   start(event) {    
       socket.emit("voice", {
         msg: event.currentTarget.message
       });

       socket.on("voice-reply", result => {
          console.log(result);
  });
}
```

But when I run this start function with button of vuejs, 
socket.on("voice-reply") is repeated one  more time. 
For example,

```
console.log(result)
```

after button click,

```
console.log(result)
console.log(result)
```

after button click,

```
console.log(result)
console.log(result)
console.log(result)
```

it runs like this. Could you explain why socket.on is run increasing one more time?
Thank you so much for reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.on` creates an `eventListener` which fires every time the event is emitted.  By including `socket.on` in your `start` action, you are creating a new `eventListener` every time you call `start` (by clicking the button), and each one of those listeners logs to the console.  You shouldn't be creating a listener in the same block of emitting the event.

Create a new action like `setupListeners` and call that only once from somewhere else, maybe in your component (such as in the `created` lifecycle hook) or from some other action:

```
const actions = {
    start(event) {    
        socket.emit("voice", {
            msg: event.currentTarget.message
        });
    },
    setupListeners() {
        socket.on("voice-reply", result => {
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
}
```